# Correct way to display a custom field in a custom content type page template

Tags: entities

I'm using Drupal 7 with a custom content type called "lesson". In this custom content type I have a custom field named "field_lesson_objective". I'd like to be able to wrap this in a custom div, so I thought it would be pretty simple to open up my custom page template "page--lesson.tpl.php", remove "", and replace that with something that would display the field, but I'm having no luck finding a solution.

Perhaps I'm going about this all wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figured this out. I copied node.tpl.php to my templates directory in my theme, and then duplicated that with the name of of custom content type:

node--lesson.tpl.php

I was then able to display my custom field with this:

```
<?php
   echo render($content['field_lesson_objective']);
?>
```