# Ouput Node Reference Field Title in Drupal 7

Tags: theming, nodes

When creating templates in Drupal 6 I can output just the title for the value of a node reference field like so:

```
echo $node->field_example[0]['safe']['title'];
```

I'm trying to do the same thing in Drupal 7 - I've tried many variations like the examples below but the output is always blank or throws an error:

```
print $content->field_example['und']['0']['node']['title'];

print $content['field_example']['#object']['field_example']['und']['0']['node']['title'];
```

Any help on how to grab the 'title' value is much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Correct way to display a custom field in a custom content type page template](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34301/correct-way-to-display-a-custom-field-in-a-custom-content-type-page-template)

Comment: Have you tried debugging the `$node` and `$content` variables to see what you've got available?

Answer (score 1):

```
print $field_example[0]['node']->title;
```

This ended up being the syntax needed to pull just the title from the value of a node reference field.